# Android: File.exists returns true when it should return false

Tags: android, file, exists

I have a bizarre problem. I write a file to the SD card and then I remove the SD card. With the card removed, I then check for the existence of the file with File.exists.

The path to the file clearly indicates /mnt/sdcard/MyAppFolder/.....

So with:

```
File f = new File(filename);

Boolean exists = f.exists();
```

it returns true. How is this possible. The SD card is not even inserted. I stopped and re-ran the app but it always returns true. Wow Android is super!! It even keeps a connection to your SD card no matter where it is. Seriously folks, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you unmount the SD card before physically removing it?

Comment: Oh. Wait a second. I'm debugging in Eclipse and when I removed the physical SD card, I completely forgot that the Android SDK probably is creating a virtual SD card. Sorry for asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 'File.exists' return true, even though 'Files.exists' in the NIO 'Files' class returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520179/why-does-file-exists-return-true-even-though-files-exists-in-the-nio-files)

Comment: Just had this problem, and it turns out the file.exists() was always true when inside a try..catch block ?! Taking it out of that block fixed it for me