# file.exists() returns true although is does NOT exist

Tags: java, android

Using this code

```
new File(this.getExternalFilesDir("APP NAME").getPath()).exists())
```

or

```
this.getExternalFilesDir("APP NAME").getPath()).exists()
```

always returns true although I'm sure the file does not exist. What is the problem here?

My question is different from this one [Why does 'File.exists' return true, even though 'Files.exists' in the NIO 'Files' class returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520179) because android file system doesn't depend on nio.files class.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520179/why-does-file-exists-return-true-even-though-files-exists-in-the-nio-files

Comment: That's a java not an android question. nio.Files is not a part of android classes.

Comment: that is actually not a `FILE`, but a `DIRECTORY`

Comment: Yes I know. But how can that make a difference ?