# File.exists() return 'false' for existing file on Samba share network folder

Tags: java, samba

I know for sure that the file exists on Samba share. But `file.exists()` return `'false'` for it. 
Another system puts this file in a Samba share folder and notifies our application that the file is uploaded. Than we invoke `file.exists()` for check this and get `'false'`

```
Path sourceFile = ... 
sourceFile.toFile().exists() 
//return 'false' for existing file with path like \\share1\mc\logs.txt
```

Maybe the file has not yet been completely written or has not been completely closed, could that affect the result `file.exists()`?

Comment: Just for clarification: are you using the package `java.io` or `java.nio.file`?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi I may be missing a subtility of your question, but there's no `java.io.Path`, only `java.nio.file.Path`

Comment: can you print out the path and post it and the result of `sourceFile.toFile()`?  Shown code is working fine for me

Comment: @aaron You're right, I only looked at `File`. Must be NIO then.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi NIO only to represent Path and get `File`; the real work is done by `java.io.File#exists`

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least the behaviour you're observing is covered by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-)

> false if the file does not exist *or its existence cannot be determined*

(emphasis added).

Might be related to this question here: [Why does 'File.exists' return true, even though 'Files.exists' in the NIO 'Files' class returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30520179/60462), though the answers seem a bit inconclusive to me.

Comment: Here used File.exists() method, not Files.exists(...), but thanks for link!